# custom theme You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I'm using custom theme with code below:-

custom_styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>


</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <application
    android:name="com.exmaple.test.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.exmaple.test.FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Menucentre.java

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_bar_smart, null);
    cView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(HeaderBackground));
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView, layout);
```

Output with this error:

```
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MenuCenter}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:976)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:855)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:267)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.setContentView(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:75)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.setContentView(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:67)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.setContentView(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:59)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at com.example.test.MenuCenter.onCreate(MenuCenter.java:70)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
02-25 10:14:15.645: E/AndroidRuntime(6542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

with

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: after replace my this code this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
 this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.nav_bar); got error with You cannot combine custom title with other title features

Comment: You have to call `requestWindowFeature` before `super.onCreate()` with ActionBarSherlock as per [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/310#issuecomment-7350074)